# Execute queries at some previous point in time

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to "remember" some point in time, and give it an identifier, so that I can later reference it in queries and get the results from the database as it was then?

If such a mechanism exists, how lightweight is it? Would it be acceptable to generate tens of there "snapshots" a second?

I think I can get something like this with transactions that expose their IDs, but I'm worried this is too heavy weight and I'm not sure if a transaction can be exited, but not destroyed.

Comment: You are wanting to submit a sql statement, but bring results back that match a particular point in time? Do those results exist in your data, or you hoping that there is some mechanism to have them remembered?

Comment: I can only think of making a database dump:) even transactions are limited to the records you touched. (And there's an upper limit to them.)

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, then this is a function of your data. Do you store history for your records with a validity period (valid_from, valid_to) for each record? I believe that Postgres has a temporal table extension to make it close to [sql2011 sql temporal standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011#Temporal_support), but you are facing a lot of work to update your schema.

Comment: You are looking for so called "time travels" - it was removed from postgresql in some very old version 6.x but there are extension which allow it. But I think you understand that have these points in time available means to store all those data in database. So over time your database will multiply very quickly

Comment: you appear to be describing point in time recovery... except PITR isn't driven by SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access data you don't keep, but there are approaches to schema design that let you do this kind of thing. If you're really interested, read about bi-temporal tables and SQL:2011. Two great books are *Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL* by Richard Snodgrass (also available as a [free PDF on his website](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~rts/publications.html)) and *Bitemporal Data* by Tom Johnston.

A less academic approach, which is not *bi*-temporal but lets you access old data, is described in [this talk from 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRgni5q0YM8).

Another approach, also not bi-temporal, is using the [`temporal_tables` extension](http://pgxn.org/dist/temporal_tables/) (with [github here](https://github.com/arkhipov/temporal_tables)).

I think the biggest challenge is handling old data as your schema evolves over time. For instance, you add a new `NOT NULL` column. What do you do with all the old records? As far as I know, there is very little that addresses this, either in the research or the tools.

Comment: In my use case the snapshots wouldn't persist very long. Certainly not through a schema change.

Comment: In that case I would consider that talk from PGConf US 2015 (the YouTube link). It seems pretty easy to set up, and you can just frequently purge the old data.

Comment: Just FYI, Oracle has this type of thing if you configure your database to allow it. It's called flashback query. If I remember correctly, you had to have your archive logs kept online somewhere.. but it's been a while. Definitely used to use it all the time back when I was an oracle DBA. https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/flashback-query-10g